# landscape layout for 1080*1920 devices

Tags: android, layout, screen-size

I want to create an landscape layout for 1080*1920 phones. In portrait mode I used the

```
layout-xxhdpi
```

folder which works fine.

Should I define a folder with the name

```
layout-land-xxhdpi
```

for landscape?

Comment: `Should I define a folder ...` If your Views positioning is different from the Portrait mode (which is likely to be), then yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, landscape mode use resource from `layout-land-*` folders.

[Android documentation about supporting different screens.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)